# How to query a database by date range

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, date-range, date

I'm making a Java program that will determine the `JComboBox` values set default to get the user's input to choose within daily, weekly, monthly and yearly. Now I have an idea in monthly but my query returning an Exception error. Here is my code.

```
            Calendar timer = Calendar.getInstance();
            timer.getTime();
            int month = timer.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = timer.get(Calendar.YEAR);        
            int day = timer.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
            int week = timer.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

            String combovalue = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

               if(combovalue.equals("Monthly")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date between January and February";
                    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(day));
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    pst.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Monthly" );
                    }catch (Exception e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1 );
                    }
```

Comment: `String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date between January and February";` has no parameters, so `pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(day));` is going to give you issues

Comment: yes, and I have no idea what to do with that query.. searching more codes..

Comment: Also, does swing code help us undertand your jdbc question? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please quote your exception message verbatim. Such messages tend to tell a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just start with...

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date between January and February";
pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(day));
```

The `sql` is invalid to start with, `January` and `February` should be quoted, but, since you're trying to use a `PreparedStatement`, there are no parameters, so `pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(day));` will fail ... I mean, where is parameter `1` anyway?

I would recommend having a closer look at [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Instead, you should be using something ***like***...

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date between ? and ?";
try (PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pst.setString(1, new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime()));
    pst.setString(2, new java.sql.Date(toDate.getTime()));
    try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Monthly");
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ep);
}
```

This assumes that `sales.date` is an actual date/time type.

There are a number of ways to get the start/end dates, one of the better ways would be to use the newer Date/Time API, instead of the defunct `Calendar` API, for example...

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);
```

You would then need to use...

```
pst.setString(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDate));
pst.setString(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(endDate));
```

to make them compatible with `java.sql.Date`

## Updated...

Just to verify I wasn't going insane, I wrote this simple test class...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test")) {
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
            String make = "create table if not exists Test (id bigint identity, value date)";
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                stmt.execute(make);
            }
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                System.out.println(">> Remove " + stmt.executeUpdate("delete from test") + " rows");
            }
            LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 25);
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                insert(con, ld);
                ld = ld.plusDays(5);
            }
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from test")) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        int count = rs.getInt(1);
                        System.out.println("Found " + count + " rows");
                    }
                }
            }

//          String sql = "select value from test";
//          try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
//              try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
//                  while (rs.next()) {
//                      System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
//                  }
//              }
//          }

            LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 1);
            LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);
            String sql = "select value from test where value between ? and ?";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDate));
                stmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(endDate));
                System.out.println(startDate);
                System.out.println(endDate);
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        java.sql.Date date = rs.getDate(1);
                        System.out.println(date);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void insert(Connection con, LocalDate ld) throws SQLException {       
        String sql = "insert into test (value) values (?)";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(ld);
            stmt.setDate(1, date);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

}
```

It uses a [H2 Database Engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) in memory database, populates it with 100 dates from December 25th 2017 to May 9th 2019.

It then performs a query for values between January 1st 2018 and February 1st 2018 and prints

```
2018-01-01
2018-02-01
2018-01-04
2018-01-09
2018-01-14
2018-01-19
2018-01-24
2018-01-29
```

So, you need to make sure that you have valid values in your database.  If you're not getting anything in your table, first, verify that the database actually returns something and that your query is valid for the data you are trying to get

Comment: I used it but my table shows a blank results.. hehe.. I used it like this:

LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 14);
    LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);

Comment: And there are values between Jan 14th and Feb 14th 2018

Comment: what values to add?

Comment: Go to your database, list all the rows for `sales`, verify that there are values between the specified dates (mind you, if you have sales in the future you're doing a good job)

Comment: there is a values in Feb 14th 2018  but none on Jan 14th

Comment: I inputted values between Jan 14th and Feb 14th 2018 but my table prints a blank table :)

Comment: Okay, so instead of building the `TableModel`, loop through the `ResultSet` and verify that the values are been returned from the database

Comment: Is this date format "MMMM d, yyyy" affects the result of the table sir? that is my format used in my column 'date'

Comment: Nope, the date format is irrelevant- that’s why I’m using Date based objects - this also assumes that the column is a date type

Comment: thank you so much... :) the date format is the error.. :)

Comment: @GerickAntoninoMartinez With all due respect, if you're relying on the date formats, then you're doing something wrong.  The data should be stored in the database as a date type and you should be using the drivers capabilities to perform any required conversions, this relieves you of the burden of having to worry about the format at any level.  Java's data/time class are format agnostic - that's the format they "print" is nothing more then debug information.

Comment: ok thanks @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

Define Sales.date and / or Try TRUNC(date) function. Or use Numeric value like

BETWEEN '01-JAN-2018' AND '01-FEB-2018'.

Remember to insert '' marks Around the date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write date between in numeric values Jan as '01-01-2018', Feb '02-01-2018' so `SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date between '01-01-2018' and '02-01-2018'`

```
Calendar timer = Calendar.getInstance();
            timer.getTime();
            int month = timer.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = timer.get(Calendar.YEAR);        
            int day = timer.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
            int week = timer.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

          String combovalue = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

               if(combovalue.equals("Monthly")) {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date between 01-01-2018 and 02-01-2018";
                    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(day));
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    pst.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Monthly" );
                    }catch (Exception e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1 );
                    }
```